# Spring Cloud security issues

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-cloud

I've upgraded a Spring Cloud project from a Spring Boot project, which the Spring Security module has been extracted from other modules and now the annotation `@PreAuthorize` is useless.

How to resume the `@PreAuthorize` or is there another way to accomplish the authorization?

```java
@PreAuthorize("@el.check('student:del')")
public ResponseEntity<Object> delete(@RequestBody Set<Long> schoolId) {
        return studentService.delete(schoolId);
}
```

The annotation is active only if the class extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and has an annotation `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)`.

Comment: Why do you remove Spring Security, if you want to use it? Add it back.

Comment: I didn't remove it ,it's just not in the same module so, the functions were separated to run independently so it doesn't work anymore

Comment: What module? Show your dependencies. However, you could allway add it back.